# What happened to https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/?

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following section in `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3"
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.5.1'
    }
}
```

Unfortunately https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/ returns 404.

Is this temporary out of service or by design behavior?

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't seem to matter as the plugins are still being resolved, they just redirect to **jcenter** anyway.

Comment: What does it mean? How they can be resolved without repository?

Comment: For example: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/ajoberstar/gradle-git/1.5.1 redirects to https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ajoberstar/gradle-git/1.5.1/